# Can a Matlab M-script be stopped by a statement in the script?

Tags: matlab

A very simple, and perhaps obvious, question: How can I abort execution of a Matlab M-script using a statement within the script?

This is analogous to calling `return` in the middle of a function to end it immediately.

Comment: Abort and returning are two different things, do you want to `return` or do want to `exit(1)`?

Comment: @Mikhail `exit` quits Matlab, that's probably not what he wants ...

Comment: return works just as well in a script as it does in a function.

Comment: @grantnz Wow, didn't know that. Then nevermind my answer ...

Comment: The alternative is `keyboard` which causes you to go into the debugger; it's also a useful command in a script. You can then examine variables, even change them, and continue with `dbcont` or decide to stop the debugging with `dbquit`. But Mikhail is right that `return` best matches what you asked for. You were so close - but apparently never tried it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If [`return`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/return.html) is not want you need, I think you want to use [`break`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/break.html)

break terminates the execution of a Matlab code. For example, statements in the loop that appear after the break statement are not executed.

In nested loops, break exits only from the loop in which it occurs. Control passes to the statement that follows the end of that loop.

Answer (score 8):

As of Matlab R2015b `break` can no longer be used to pre-terminate a script.  A `break` can now only be used to a for-loop.  The code will not run and an error will be thrown.  This was technically always true, but it is now enforced.

The proper way is to use `return`

Comment: `while` loop also.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can with the help of

> return;

Return works in Matlab-scripts like it does in functions.

e.g.

```
    function [ point ] = PointDoubling( x,y,p,a )
    %UNTITLED2 Summary of this function goes here
    %   Detailed explanation goes here
    if y==0
        point='Not calculated';
        return;
    end
    a2=(3*(x^2))+a;
    b2=(2*y);
    i=1;
    while 1
        if mod(b2*i,p)==1
        break;
    end
        i=i+1;
    end
    s=mod(a2*i,p);
    x1=mod(((s^2)-(2*x)),p);
    y1=mod(((-y)+(s*(x-x1))),p);
    point=[x1,y1];
    end
```